# initialization after switch-statement

Tags: java, eclipse, initialization, switch-statement

Why does it says that 'decimalNum' may have not been initialized, although it has been initialized in one of the cases in the switch statement?

```
    Scanner  s = new Scanner(System.in);

    char romeDigit;
    int decimalNum;
    boolean  inputValid = true;

    System.out.println("Please enter a rome digit: ");
    romeDigit = s.next().charAt(0);

    switch (romeDigit)  {
        case 'i':
        case 'I':
            decimalNum = 1;
            break;
        case 'v':
        case 'V':
            decimalNum = 5;
            break;
        case 'x':
        case 'X':
            decimalNum = 10;
            break;
        default:
            inputValid = false;
            break;
    }

    if (inputValid)
        System.out.println**("Num is" + decimalNum);**
    else
        System.out.println("Invalid input!");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not enough to initialize `decimalNum` in some of the cases. It must be initialized in all the cases, including the default case.

```
    default:
        inputValid = false;
        decimalNum = -1; // it doesn't really matter what you put here, since
                         // you are using a flag to determine if the value is valid
        break;
```

Answer (score -1):

or just add int decimalNum=0; where you declare the variable to avoid the error